# How to implement datatable in a gridview in a master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, webforms, master-pages

I am using the AdminLTE library and have designed my master with 2 content placeholders; one in the head section and another in the body section. I am unable to get my gridview to render its content in a datatable.

I populate the gridview via a shared method from a class file which works fine. I have tried to write the Javascript document.ready function in the head section of my aspx form but the gridview seems not to recognize the function.

This is the markup

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title">List of available regions</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <asp:GridView ID="grvRegions" runat="server" class="table table-bordered table-striped"
            EmptyDataText="Empty region list" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Region" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditRegion" required="required" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRegion" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Region")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtUpdate" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtCancel" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtRemove" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is the method that retrieves the data for the gridview

Public Shared Sub FillTabularData(container As Object, spName As String, Optional param As SqlParameter = Nothing)

```
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(spName, connection)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        If param IsNot Nothing Then
            command.Parameters.Add(param)
        End If
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If
        Dim dTable As New DataSet
        Dim dAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        dAdapter.Fill(dTable)
        container.DataSource = dTable
        container.DataBind()

End Sub
```

This is the calling of the "FillTabularData" method in my code behind file for the gridview

```
Sub BindData()
    FillTabularData(grvRegions, "sp_list_regions")
    grvRegions.UseAccessibleHeader = True
    grvRegions.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
End Sub
```

I expect the output to be rendered in a datatable with paging, sorting, searching and number of rows per page capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (I am not familiar with vb.net coding, please check the syntax)

```
Sub BindData()
 Dim dt As New DataSet 
 dt= FillTabularData("sp_list_regions")
 grvRegions.DataSource = dTable
 grvRegions.DataBind()
 grvRegions.UseAccessibleHeader = True
 grvRegions.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
End Sub


Public Shared Function FillTabularData(spName As String, Optional param As SqlParameter = Nothing) As DataSet
Dim command As New SqlCommand(spName, connection)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    If param IsNot Nothing Then
        command.Parameters.Add(param)
    End If
    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connection.Open()
    End If
    Dim dTable As New DataSet
    Dim dAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable)
    return dTable

End Function
```

Comment: Change `DataTable dt= ` to `Dim dt As DataTable =`.

Comment: Change `End Sub` to `End Function`.

Comment: You cannot return a `DataSet` when your Function type is `DataTable`. Either change the Function type or return a `DataTable`. `Return dTable.Tables(0)`

Comment: You shouldn't have to check the `ConnectionState` if you keep you database objects local and use `Using...End Using` blocks. You don't have to open a connection when using a `DataAdapter`. However if it finds it open, it leaves it open.

Comment: If you want a generic function to fill a data table use an array of param. It would be very common to have more than one parameter in a where clause. You would have to add a loop to add the parameters.